# Using Bootstrap in Live site

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi. I have just started to mess around with Bootstrap. I have learned HTML, CSS, Javascript and PHP over the past nine months. I would like to start putting websites online in this coming summer. For purposes of ease and responsive programming I would like to know if first of all if it is frowned upon in any way? Secondly, in terms of editing bootstrap CSS should I copy the bootstrap one and put in my own edit's? Or is there a better practice for this ?
Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my personal experience, using boostrap isn't frowned upon. Just try to make sure your sites stand out and dont' just look like default boostrap sites which after a while can start to look very template-y.

In regards to the CSS, you should NEVER touch the bootstrap.min.css file. You should make your own CSS file and import that into your files. If you need to override anything in bootstrap, changing it in your other CSS file will override the bootstrap css.

Comment: Thanks! No il def have it looking different just it really makes the whole responsive element quite simple! I know not to edit the original CSS, I was wondering if I should make my own copy of Bootstrap and then put in edit's. Thanks your answer really helped!

Comment: @Anindya is right. Never ever fouch the responsive css from bootstrap. Write your own css and load that in as lastm to overwrite the bootstrap file,

Comment: @Eoin2211: You shouldn't be making a copy of bootstrap and making edits, you should have your own stylesheet all together. Something like "styles.css" or "main.css" and in that you should just override what you need to, for example body { font-size: 1.5em; }. that will override bootstrap's default font size, you should NOT be just copy/pasting the whole boostrap css into a new file to edit.